bevel + extrude, how to get clean topology?
What's a proper way to do this recess with a proper topology?



Maybe try using this topology? Create a face inside the face and bevel its vertices with Ctrl+B then V (to switch from edge bevel to vertex bevel), then use the Knife tool to cut some edge loops.


How did you achieve this effect? knife tool and then inset?

create a face inside the face and bevel its vertices with Ctrl B then V (to switch from edge bevel to vertex bevel), then use the knife to cut some edge loops

You can use this simple topology


Then simply add Subdivision Surface Modifier:


